# Vue router is not working when new route added

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-router

My app is working fine in localhost with this configuration, I use XAMMP in localhost. but when I deployed my app in a VPS with Linux (ubunto) OS, I got this problem. In the first days they worked fine too, but recently when I added the last route (categories) and did 'npm run production' my routes suddenly stopped working.

> When I click on a router-link the URL doesn't even change.

I changed my webserver from nginx to apache, but it doesn't make any difference.
my routes are like this:

```
const Index = resolve => {
   require.ensure(['./frontend-components/main-content/index'], () => {
      resolve(require('./frontend-components/main-content/index'));
   });    
};
const news = resolve => {
   require.ensure(['./frontend-components/single/news'], () => {
       resolve(require('./frontend-components/single/news'));
   });    
};
const lists = resolve => {
    require.ensure(['./frontend-components/single/lists'], () => {
        resolve(require('./frontend-components/single/lists'));
    });    
};
const categories = resolve => {
   require.ensure(['./frontend-components/single/categories'], () => {
       resolve(require('./frontend-components/single/categories'));
   });    
};

export const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Index},
    {path: '/articles/:article_id/:slug',component: news,name: 'articles'},
    {path: '/lists/:article_id/:slug',component: lists,name: 'lists'},
    {path: '/categories/:cat_id/:slug', component: categories},
]
```

and my webpack configuration is :

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/fr-app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/fr-app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({processCssUrls: false})
   .webpackConfig({ output: { filename: '[name].js', chunkFilename: 
    'js/[name].app.js', publicPath: '/' } });
```

I have this error when I click on a router-link:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

and it refers to this line to source code:

```
// Execute the module function
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

Comment: Aren't the async component factory functions meant to return a `Promise`? `resolve => { ... }` is **not** a promise. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Comment: Also, Webpack recommends using dynamic `import` instead of `require.ensure`. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: @Phil I don't know anything about webpack language syntax. would you please submit an answer about the correct route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`require.ensure`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure) is the legacy Webpack syntax, which is superceded by `import`. And as @Phil pointed out, `resolve => {/*...*/}` itself does not create a `Promise`, which is needed for lazy loading routes. You probably meant something like this:

```
const foo = new Promise(resolve => {
  require.ensure( './path/to/foo', () => resolve(require('./path/to/foo')) );
});
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/foo',
    component: foo
  }
];
```

However, the [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) recommends the `import` syntax for lazy loading routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/foo',
    component: () => import('./path/to/foo')
  }
];
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j6xypz4o1)

Comment: thanks. your answer works but I had to change import to System.import because of webpack issues.